# How to check if condition for 5 seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to check an *if* condition for 5 seconds? This *if* condition should be true for 5 seconds to execute its code.

```
function checkcodition() {
  var a,b;
  if (a == 0 && b == 1) // <--this condition should be true for 5 seconds ??
  {
    console.log(" This line should display after 5 seconds");
  }
}
```

EDIT :

```js
function valupdate() {
  $('p').each(function(index, element) {
    var number = Math.round(Math.random());
    $(element).text(number);
  });
}
valupdate();

// cache DOM elements for quick reference
var demo1 = $('#demo1');
var demo2 = $('#demo2');
var demo3 = $('#demo3');

// store their current values in object
// this is how we will reference their previous values
var stored_values = {
  demo1: demo1.text(),
  demo2: demo2.text(),
  demo3: demo3.text()
};

// loop through all elements
// get their current value from .text()
// get their PREVIOUS value from the object we made above
// compare values with our custom compare function (define below)
// finally, save the current value in our object
function checkValues(item, msg) {
  var element_id = item.attr('id');
  var currentValue = item.text();
  var previousValue = stored_values[element_id];
  compareValues(currentValue, previousValue, element_id, msg);
  stored_values[element_id] = currentValue;
}

// compare values passed in, and determine what to do
function compareValues(current, previous, elementID, smstext) {
  if (previous == 0 && current == 1) //check conditions for 5 seconds to execute below code.
  {
    console.log('Sending SMS for : ' + elementID + ':' + smstext + '!!!');
  }
  else {
    return; // do nothing
  }
}

var msg1 = "Message1";
var msg2 = "Message2";
var msg3 = "Message3";

setInterval(function() {
  valupdate();
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  checkValues(demo1, msg1);
  //checkValues(demo2,msg2);
  //checkValues(demo3,msg3);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Test SMS Triggers</h2>
    
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be that when you set either a or b to relevant values you also set a timeout to check them again in 5 seconds.  There is no built-in *"make sure this is like that for x amount of time"*, so you'll have to use your head on this one.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't ever going to change in this particular example…

Comment: @deceze is right, it doesn't make sense to define *a* and *b* in the same function. Ranjit, perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want this logic in my application of sending sms. Value of a remains 0, but b value should be 1 for 5 seconds on every call before triggering sms function. Sometimes b value becomes 1 but again reset to 0 before 5 seconds.

Comment: You probably want some logic like: *when `b` is set and it's of the right value, start a timeout to trigger a function after 5 seconds. When `b` is set again to some other value and there's a running timeout, stop the timeout.* In other words, some *setter* function for `b`. How exactly to realise that in your specific case we don't know.

Comment: Where and how do you set the values for a and b? Can you include that in your code example?

Comment: @deceze It's just an example, but values of a and b are live and changing in real time ( becomes 0 or 1)

Comment: Answer the questions and you may get some help then :)

Comment: You would need to check the condition on a very short interval and reset if it becomes false.

Comment: Please check the fiddle for complete test code https://jsfiddle.net/0mt5abxd/

Comment: @Yoshi Even checking *very often* cannot tell you whether a value remained *constant* during a certain period; if it changes back and forth very quickly you might not catch that. Not to mention that it's insanely inefficient. You catch value changes through an observer or setter pattern.

Comment: @deceze I understand that. Obviously the whole setup is *problematic* (at best). Though, supposedly no change of the *surrounding* code is possible, then, and only then, I don't see a better option than simply running an interval.

Comment: @Yoshi - Why are you assuming you can't change any code??  That's not stated in the question.  OP just wants an answer, and the very first sentence of the very first comment is a solid suggestion.  Sorry, but checking periodically is horrible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169928/discussion-on-question-by-ranjit-singh-shekhawat-how-to-check-if-condition-for-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to handle changes of a given element.

**Update**: Seeing your previous question, I changed my answer, as I think I misjudged what you wanted to do. It now does the following:

- wait for an element's `innerText` to transition from `'0'` to `'1'` and if it stays `'1'` for 5 seconds, trigger the callback

```js
// randomly change values
(function valUpdate() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p')).forEach((el) => {
    el.innerText = Math.round(Math.random());
  });

  setTimeout(valUpdate, 1000);
})();


// helpers

const onMutation = (target, cb, config = {childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true}) => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    cb(target, observer.disconnect.bind(observer), mutations);
  });

  observer.observe(target, config);
};

const onChange = (selector) => (target, cb) => {
  let prev = selector(target);

  onMutation(target, (_, disconnect) => {
    const current = selector(target);

    if (prev !== current) {
      cb(prev, current, target, disconnect);
    }

    prev = current;
  });
};

const ifStatic = (decider) => (time, cb) => {
  let to;

  return (...args) => {
    if (decider(...args)) {
      to = setTimeout(cb, time, ...args);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(to);
    }
  };
};

// setup

const onInnerTextChange = onChange((el) => el.innerText);
const ifValidFor = ifStatic((prev, current) => prev === '0' && current === '1');
const sendSms = (message, stop = false) => (prev, current, el, done) => {
  console.log('Sending SMS for:', el.id, 'Message', message);
  stop && done();
};

onInnerTextChange(document.querySelector('#demo1'), ifValidFor(5000, sendSms('Message 1')));
onInnerTextChange(document.querySelector('#demo2'), ifValidFor(5000, sendSms('Message 2', true)));
onInnerTextChange(document.querySelector('#demo3'), ifValidFor(5000, sendSms('Message 3', true)));
```

```html
<h2>Test SMS Triggers</h2>
<p id="demo1">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<p id="demo3">0</p>
```

---

Note that, depending on how the node is changed, you might need to fiddle with the [MutationObserverInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) configuration. Above I used:

```
{ childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true }
```

---

You'll need [at least IE11 for this to work](https://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver). If you need to support older versions, then there might be other solutions, though I dare not utter them. ;)

---

For the sake of showing how simple this could be done with *better* tools, here's a [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) version:

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

const fromMutation = (target, config) => new Observable((observer) => {
  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    observer.next(mutations);
  });

  mutationObserver.observe(target, config);

  return () => {
    mutationObserver.disconnect();
  };
});

const sendSmsAfter = (delay) => (el) => fromMutation(el, {characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true})
  .map(() => el.innerText)
  .startWith(el.innerText)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .pairwise()
  .switchMap(([prev, current]) => prev === '0' && current === '1'
    ? Observable.of(el).delay(delay)
    : Observable.empty()
  )
;

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#demo1, #demo2, #demo3');

Observable
  .from(elements)
  .mergeMap(sendSmsAfter(5000))
  .subscribe((el) => {
    console.log('sms go!', el.id);
  })
;

Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .switchMapTo(elements)
  .subscribe((el) => {
    el.innerText = Math.round(Math.random());
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@^5/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>

<h2>Test SMS Triggers</h2>
<p id="demo1">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<p id="demo3">0</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use browser APIs `setTimeout` function.

This example will only check the condition AFTER five seconds, not DURING five second interval. If you want to make sure the condition stays true during whole interval, you should probably implement some `onValueChange()` type event.

```
function checkCodition() {
    let a, b;
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (a === 0 && b === 1) {
            console.log(" This line shoud display after 5 seconds");
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Additional info:

You should use tripple equality sign `===`, use `let` instead of `var` and `camelCase` insted of `lowercase` for function names.

Comment: Note that this doesn't test whether the variables have particular values ***for*** 5 seconds, it tests whether the variables have specific values at a particular point in time *after* 5 seconds. That may or may not be entirely different.

Comment: The problem is that the conditions will never be true, since the variables are never assigned any values